# Ivy: Install all dependencies to a shared repository

Tags: dependencies, repository, installation, shared, ivy

As the title says, this is about [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) which we use for Dependency resolution for Java projects, mainly. We just set up Ivy, so I may not know everything.

Here is my problem: Let's say I have a module A that depends on B, C, D, E and whatnot. I know I can publish module A easily to my shared repo. That works. What I want is, that Ivy copies all modules that module A depends on from their public repositories to out shared repository. I've checked the `ivy:install` task, which is not exactly what I want (Or may I misunderstand how it works). The [example](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/install.html) says:

```
<ivy:install organisation="apache" module="commons-lang" revision="2.0" from="ivyrep" to="myfsresolver"/>
```

The `from` and `to` attributes are mandatory and from the example, I guess it works for one dependency that is inside a known repository and has a specific revision. And I would have to write an ANT task that explicitely installs every dependency separately.

What I need, is to tell Ivy
- Perform Resolve
- Publish/install all found dependencies with their name, revision from their source repository where it has been discovered to my shared repository

So the `to` attribute might make sense, probably a `conf` attribute but not `name`, `revision` and `from`.

So, I'm looking for a task like

```
<ivy:install to="shared"/>
```

that will transiently install all dependencies (even excluding the dependent module itself)  to my shared repository so we can build even without an internet connection or when a public repository is closed.

Comment: What is the underlying _problem_ you need to solve? A maven proxy might be enough.

Comment: We're currently in a transition from a mainly NetBeans/IDE driven development to an automatable ANT/ivy driven approach that allows continous integration. The problem we need to solve or what we're trying to achieve is being independent of public repositories and our internet connection. Libraries and whole repositories may not be available on the long term. Thus, as soon a released version is available, all dependencies must be available from our internal shared repo.

Comment: I've found that things like this is easy to get if you go fully maven but then you get a lot of other restrictions.  Why did you choose ant+ivy?

Comment: We also evaluated Maven. But we chose Ivy because of its simplicity. For most projects we "ported" to ANT/Ivy it just worked like magic. And yet, it's quite powerful using configurations for more complex deployment setups. Maybe we'll regret it a some point in the future we we meet some issues that can't be solved with Ivy. But right now,  it performs pretty well.

Comment: Sounds like an upstream proxy will be enough. Any artifact downloaded will then be cached in the proxy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the best solution, but what would probably work is to use 2 repositories.

Use the first repository for publishing your module A, and then use ivy to copy A and all its dependencies to the second repository. For this you can use the `install` task. In the `from` attribute you would give a [chain resolver](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/resolver/chain.html) that points to both the first repository and the public repository, and in the `to` attribute you give your shared repository.

I have not use Ivy in such a setup, but we successfully use `install` to copy artifacts including all their transitive dependencies from a public repository to our own repository, so I don't see why this shouldn't work.

Comment: This is kind of an ugly hack but it does work! I already had an ant task `publish-local` that did `<ivy:resolve/>
  <ivy:publish status="release" resolver="local" overwrite="true" >
   <artifacts pattern="${dist.dir}/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
  </ivy:publish>`. Then I've added a new task `install` that called `<ivy:install module="${ivy.module}" from="local" to="shared" organisation="${ivy.organisation}" revision="${ivy.revision}" overwrite="true" transitive="true"/>` that depends on `publish-local` and `init` which sets up some environment variables and calls `<ivy:info/>`

Answer (score 2):

This is based on Philipp's answer and my unreadable comment. I just wanted to give some examples. I' always have a common `build-ivy.xml` that I include in each projects `build.xml`. This common build script contains the following tasks, that are needed to install the module including dependencies to your shared repository.

This will read the ivy.xml to populate the variables.

```
<target name="init">
    <ivy:settings file="${env.IVY_SETTINGS}/ivysettings.xml"/>
    <ivy:info/>
</target>
```

The next task depends on various task to clean, compile, package etc that you need to implement yourself.

```
<target depends="init,clean-build,clean-dist,dist,package-doc,package-sources" name="publish-local">
    <ivy:resolve/>
    <ivy:publish status="release" resolver="local" overwrite="true" >
        <artifacts pattern="${dist.dir}/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
    </ivy:publish>
</target>
```

This task will now install the current module including dependencies transitively into the share repository.

```
<target name="install" depends="publish-local">
    <ivy:install module="${ivy.module}" from="local" to="shared" organisation="${ivy.organisation}" revision="${ivy.revision}" overwrite="true" transitive="true"/>
</target>
```